# Break out a loop from within a (yielded) block inside the loop

Tags: ruby

```
jobs.each do |job|
  msg job.name do
    break if stop_all_jobs?
    job.run!
  end
end   

def msg(msg, &block)
  puts 'START ' + msg
  yield
  puts 'END ' + msg
end
```

In the above example `break` does not break out of the loop as expected. It only breaks out of the `msg` code block.

This seems a little odd, but I guess it is based on context, that said, how do I break out of the loop from code which is within a `yield`ed code block?

Comment: To be clear, you want to `return` from `msg` so that `"END"` is never printed? Or are you trying to simply have `job.run!` never called, but continue on with `msg`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

One way is to use `throw/catch`. No, not exceptions, Ruby has a separate control-of-flow feature that works a bit like exceptions, without all the overhead (although I must admit I'm not sure that there isn't *any* overhead in using it):

```
catch :stop_all_jobs do
  msg job.name do
    throw :stop_all_jobs if stop_all_jobs?
    job.run!
  end
end
```

You can even pass a value as the second argument to `throw` which will be the result of the `catch` block.

A potentially more readable solution would, of course, be to pack the code up in a method and use `return` in place of `break`. But that wouldn't be as fun.

Comment: throw/catch seems a bit like goto, or is it just me?

Comment: Yep. It's goto with a different name, and a return value :)

Comment: When Ruby encounters a throw, it zips back up the call stack looking for a catch block with a matching symbol. When it finds it, Ruby unwinds the stack to that point and terminates the block. Cite: http://www.ruby-doc.org/docs/ProgrammingRuby/html/tut_exceptions.html

Answer (score -2):

Use `next` instead of `break`.